# Custom Data Annotation Attribute using Metadata

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, metadata

My requirement is to create a custom data annotation attribute for my project. The requirement is to validate the min/ max length of a specific product from the database, which will be retrieved from the database using the ProductID. I have a dynamic page for each product where there are two fields called max length & min length. User inputs the values in these two fields which needs to be validated from the database. Product table contains all the products & one will be selected by passing a productId.

Please suggest some pointers to implement the above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This validation you can do only in the server side and not in client, so I see two options.

1. [Remote Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) - You can use remote validation when you want to perform the validation and show the error message through ajax.
2. [IValidatableObject](http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/4/model_validation_in_asp_net_mvc) - By implementing this interface in the class you can do both the validations at the same time and return all the validation error messages as a collection. By this way the validation will happen after the form is normally submitted.